# Non-displayable subset of CJK Unified Ideographs

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cjk

I'm using CJK Unified Ideographs characters to generate random data in my app. I've noticed the characters with the codes U+9FD6 - U+9FFF is displayed like this: "鿟".

As far as I understand this is some set of symbols like EOF and etc that don't have a representation. But I wonder what are they used for? Does anyone knows? I haven't managed to find info about this specific range.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9fd6/index.htm shows a glyph but also a warning that this is not a valid Unicode character.

Comment: https://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2014/06/9fcd-thru-9fe9.html shows an update which looks like a few of them are actually defined now.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, that's interesting! I was looking at [this table](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/4E00-9FFF). The Wikipedia's table is the same o_0

Comment: I notice that *'dispayed like this: "?"'* is rendered differently on my phone and on my desktop. In both cases I see a box glyph but perhaps not what you intended for me to see?

Comment: @tripleee on my IPhone SE I see a box of black boxes ahah) On computer I saw something like an empty box. But that doesn’t matter I guess)

Comment: If it's not consistent, I suppose it's also quite possible that some people (from the future, perhaps) actually see a well-formed Chinese character. Your question would be rather hard to understand then. See also the discussion on the [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info).